# Django CMS - Articles show as None

Tags: python, django, django-cms

Ive just install the Django CMS but each of the titles for the articles are showing as none ?
Has anyone come across this before ?

[image: screenshot]

The install is the basic install using just a base and template_1 templates as per the tutorial on the django-cms site.

When going back into each page the title is there. So the info must be being written to the database.

Thanks,

Comment: You haven't provided enough details. What are articles? Do you mean pages? What templates have you created? Where are the titles showing as none - in the admin or frontend? Where's your code? What documentation have you followed to set up CSM?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show some code that you suspect of being problematic? How did you populate the rows? Are you sure you ever assigned the titles? Did you check whether its a problem in assigning or in fetching them?

Answer (score 21):

It seams there is a problem with django CMS 2.4 and USE_I18N=False or when you only use 1 language.

https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/1715

and

https://github.com/divio/django-cms/pull/1722

Try setting LANGUAGE_CODE = "en" instead of "en-us"